# XMLHttpRequest cannot load an URL with ajax in Senchatouch-2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

```
I'm trying to get some j son data from a local server using Senchatouch-2 app:
```

I get the following message:

```
load http://localhost:8084/Sencha/senchatest. Origin http://localhost:8084 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Even If I launch my sencha app as an, I get this:

   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8084/Sencha/senchatest.Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

The web service returns data. I try to catch the data items like this:
```

// dynamic list view

```
 proxy:{
            type: 'ajax',
            method:'GET',
            model:'List.model.Mainmodel',
            url: 'http://localhost:8084/Sencha/senchatest',

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data.firstName.lastName'
              }}  

And I'm trying to get this structure:
   {"data":[{"firstName": "dhina", "lastName": "karan"},{"firstName": "dhina", "lastName": "karan"},{"firstName": "dhina", "lastName": "karan"},{"firstName": "dhina", "lastName": "karan"},{"firstName": "dhina", "lastName": "karan"},{"firstName": "dhina", "lastName": "karan"}]}
```

Do you know why I'm getting this error?

Thanks,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You are suffering from Same origin Policy.

Go through this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

This will also help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've fetched your page via the server  and not loaded it via the filesystem

Comment: @radha  Did you verify this ?